# CRM Portals date issue - date not rendering properly

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I am having an issue while retrieving a date field from CRM using Fetchxml and displaying it using web template in CRM Portals.

**Date is CRM:**

10/10/2018 00:00:00  (TimeZone UTC+10:00)

**CRM Portals (Adx studio portals) renders the below:**

09/10/2018 02:00:00 PM

Can someone suggest how to handle this?

Regards,
Rizwan Aarif

Comment: What do you want to do? Maintain the same timezone between CRM & Portal users?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Behavior and format of the date and time field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/behavior-format-date-time-field).

Specifically I think you will want to look at these elements:

> Depending on what the field represents, you can choose one of the
>   following field behaviors for portal forms and grids:
>
> - User Local: The field values are displayed in the user’s local time 
>     and formatted as per their current portal language/locale.
>
> ...
>
> You can also override the default date/time format to be used on
>   portals by creating the following site settings:
>
> ```
> DateTime/DateFormat: The date format used on the portal.
> DateTime/TimeFormat: The time format used on the portal.
> DateTime/DateTimeFormat: The format for full date and time used on the portal.
> ```
>
> By default, the portal uses the standard date/time formats specified
>   by the website language settings.